# How can I assign a key index in array with Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hi I have a form like this:

```
<tr v-for="(post, index) in posts" v-bind:index="index">
   <td>{{ post.rut }}</td>
   <td>{{ post.names }} {{ post.father_lastname }} {{ post.mother_lastname }}</td>
   <td>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" v-model="form.amount[index]" placeholder="Ingresa el monto">
   </td>
</tr>
```

How you can see it has v-model="form.amount[index]" but what I want to do it's this:

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" v-model="form.amount[post.rut]" placeholder="Ingresa el monto">
```

I mean I ant to assign my own index my custom index I wonder how can I do that??

My vuejs code is this:

```
   data: function() {
        return {
            form: {
                amount: [],
            },
```

I declared amount array in vuejs how you can see above but I need to assign my own index in array because if I send the data and I check the array in this moment, it is:

```
 0 => value, 1 => value
```

but I need to do this

```
'2714155' =>  value, '4578745' => value...
```

how can I do that? Thanks

Comment: it's better to use an object in this case

Comment: how can I do that @IgorMoraru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your data as an object, then assign value to specific keys.

```
data() {
    return {
        form: {
            amount: {},
        },
    }
}
```

You can use your desired layout as is.

```
 <input 
    type="number" 
    class="form-control" 
    id="exampleInputEmail1" 
    v-model="form.amount[post.rut]" <-- here you assign a specific key
    placeholder="Ingresa el monto">
```

Comment: I wonder how can I set 0 in amount: { } I mean how can I declared as 0 ?

Comment: @MedicinaNA Declare it as string: `amount["0"] = value` or dynamically: `amount[key.toString()] = value`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using an object instead of an array, as `javascript` doesn't have associative array's like `php`. You can achieve an associative array with the help of objects instead.

###### See the working example below:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    posts: [{
        rut: 2714155,
        names: 'John',
        father_lastname: 'Doe',
        mother_lastname: 'Foo'
      },
      {
        rut: 4578745,
        names: 'Lion',
        father_lastname: 'Doe',
        mother_lastname: 'Bar'
      }
    ],
    form: {
      amount: {
        '2714155': 1,
        '4578745': 2
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="post in posts" :key="post.rut">
      <td>{{ post.rut }}</td>
      <td>{{ post.names }} {{ post.father_lastname }} {{ post.mother_lastname }}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" v-model="form.amount[post.rut]" placeholder="Ingresa el monto">
        <span>Model Value: {{ form.amount[post.rut] }}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```